# C# WPF MVVM. Работа с Models

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Всем здравствуйте, у меня такие вопросы:

1. Вот предположим у меня есть в программе несколько моделей и есть модели-представления. Как обновлять свойства модели-представления при изменении соответствующих полей в модели не используя сторонние библиотеки (например, Prism)? Мной было изучено много литературы (может недостаточно много, чтобы я нашел ответ на свой вопрос), но ответы на эту проблему не удовлетворяют моему требованию (не использовать сторонние библиотеки).
2. Есть эта же модель, но мне нужно обновлять ее поля из стороннего кода. Допустим, есть метод, который получает данные из файла каждую секунду и эти данные должны пойти на окно (в TextBlock). Как правильно стоит обновлять эти поля в модели? Я думаю, что можно это организовать при помощи событий. Заранее спасибо!

Вот код моей программы:

```cs
internal abstract class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string PropertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(PropertyName));
        }

        protected virtual bool Set<T>(ref T field, T value, [CallerMemberName] string PropertyName = null)
        {
            if (Equals(field, value)) return false;
            field = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(PropertyName);
            return true;
        } 
    }

internal class MainWindowViewModel : ViewModel
{
    private string _Text;
    public string Text
    {
        get => _Text;
        set => Set(ref _Text, value);
    }

    internal MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        ModelText.ChangeVM += ChangeText;
    }

    internal void ChangeText(string text)
    {
        Text = text;
    }
}

internal class ModelText
    {
        //Это событие вызывается при получении text
        internal static Action<string> ChangeTextEvent;

        internal static event Action<string> ChangeVM;

        private string _text;

        public string GetText()
        {
            return _text;
        }

        internal ModelText()
        {
            ChangeTextEvent += ChangeText;
        }
        
        internal void ChangeText(string text)
        {
            _text = text;
            ChangeVM?.Invoke(_text);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Событие делаете в модели, мол "Данные обновлены", подписываетесь на него в VM слое, а в нем уже делаете нужные свойства с INPC, которые и обновят UI. Если наоборот, обновление модели из UI, то при изменении свойства в VM слое, вы вызываете метод, который запишет в модель новые данные. Вот и все.

Comment: Вы можете, пожалуйста, по подробнее расписать про событие и метод? И можно ли использовать вместо INPC в VM DependencyObject?

Comment: Ну что вы, события это основы основ языка, это ведь не фишка WPF или MVVM) Допустим вот у вас модель `class SomModel{ private int value; public int GetValue() => value; public void Increase(int val) => value += val; }`, просто как видите класс, где есть значение, метод получения, метод увеличения значения. Вот вам надо допустим знать в другом классе, что был вызван метод увеличения, вы делаете событие, допустим `public event Action<int> OnIncreasing;`, далее в методе увеличения вызываете `OnIncreasing?.Invoke(1);`, ну там, где используете модель, пишете `model.OnIncreasing += someMethod;`

Comment: где `someMethod` - это простой `void someMethod(int newValue){ ... }`, вот у вас и будет он вызываться в VM слое при изменении значения в M слое, а там уже на его основе делаете что хотите в VM. `вместо INPC в VM DependencyObject` - это две разные вещи, не? `INotifyPropertyChanged` (INPC) служит для того, чтобы оповещать UI (View слой) о том, что в VM слое было изменено значение свойства, чтоб тот обновил свой вид. Ну а `DependencyObject` это больше к контрола и прочим приблудам, механизмы привязки, а не их обновления. Ну а контролы в MVVM это View слой, а не ViewModel.

Comment: То есть, я так понял, что для каждого поля (свойства) в M слое надо делать свое событие? И эти события вызывать при изменении каких-либо полей в классе. Когда я смотрел видео про MVVM, у меня сложилось мнение, что можно вместо INPC использовать DependencyObject, но это оказывается ложное представление о действительности... И можно ли класс модели сделать статическим? Не будет ли с этим проблем?

Comment: `для каждого поля (свойства)` - почему? Вы просто логически подумайте, что именно хотите там сделать. Например, вот есть машина, у нее есть состояние, бензин, состояние двигателя и так далее. Вам надо допустим чисто узнать, что сам объект машина был изменен, делаете одно событие и в нужных местах его вызываете. Ну а если надо узнать конкретно что-то, то делаете событие под конкретное действие и также в нужном месте вызываете. Вы вольны делать что угодно) `сделать статическим` - можно, но не нужно. Если у вас появляется статика, то значит вы делаете что-то не то. Статика зло, помните это)

Comment: Я хочу привести в пример код моей программы. Можете, пожалуйста, посмотреть и оценить правильность? Где лучше его продемонстрировать? Дополнить вопрос?

Comment: Отредактируйте вопрос, добавив туда все нужное.

Comment: Немного не понимаю зачем у вас там два события, где Model тоже вдруг обновляется по некому событию. Это странно) А так, ну да, примерно это я имел ввиду, `static` только уберите, смысла нету тут вообще от него. Из дополнений: не обязательно использовать приватное поле, вы можете сделать там свойство, которое в `set` будет вызывать событие изменения, тогда вам не нужен будет метод изменения, просто `класс.Свойство = значение`. Далее, для оповещения об изменениях, как и сказал выше существует INPC, можете его использовать в модели, тогда вашим событием будет `PropertyChanged` или чет такое.

Comment: То есть в M слое можно создать такое же свойство, как в VM слое ~~~ set { Text = value; PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Text")); } ~~~ ? И тогда в VM написать свойство так: ~~~ set { modelText.Text = value; PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Text")); } ~~~ ?

Comment: Мне кажется, вы не понимаете то, что делаете. Ну вот ваш 2-й вопрос допустим, файлы каждую секунду. У вас в модели бесконечный цикл с задержкой, где есть логика чтения данных из файла, вы делаете простое событие и каждое чтение файла вызываете это событие, все, вот ваш код. А в VM слое, вы просто подписываетесь на событие, по которому вы обновите нужные свойства, вытягивая их из M слоя повторно (или из события). Вот в коде выше, это к чему? `modelText.Text = value` Не смешивайте свойства, пусть будут раздельными. А INPC почему так вызывается `PropertyChanged?.Invoke`? Куда делся `Set()`?

Comment: Просто в Set() первый параметр - это ссылка на поле (свойство не хочет читать), поэтому я не использую Set(). И мне кажется, что я тогда вообще не понимаю концепцию MVVM... Можете, пожалуйста, посоветовать мне литературу для систематизированного изучения паттерна. Спасибо за уделенное время!

Comment: Не забывайте пинговать людей через `@`, ибо я вот без уведомлений не увидел ваше сообщение. ` ссылка на поле` - ну да, так он и работает, зачем вам там свойство указывать? От свойства вам нужно только имя, а оно получается автоматически через `[CallerMemberName]`. Так что, я не знаю зачем вы убрали `Set()` в коде выше... `не понимаю концепцию MVVM` - MVVM это разделение всего на несвязанные друг с другом слои, абстракция и все в этом духе там приветствуется) Ну а книги, увы, не скажу, я лично MVVM понимал уже на практике)

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Подскажите, пожалуйста, я правильно организовал концепцию MVVM в последнем своем вопросе?

Comment: Понимаете в чем дело... MVVM, как и любой другой набор правил - это лишь рекомендации того, как следует писать код, а дальше каждый уже самостоятельно подстраивает это под свой проект. Допустим некоторые используют события, по типу `Click`, когда как в MVVM подходе используются `ICommand` и привязки. Некоторые используют как у вас `DataContext` в XAML окна, когда как по правилам, View слой не должен знать что либо о других, а тут он прям создает и руководит жизнью VM слоя.

Comment: Ну и свойства, что вы сделали, я бы по событию делал `TextToRequestTB = ...;`, когда как вы просто продублировали свойство, что тогда мешает сделать модель публичным свойством и привязать просто `{Binding Model.TextToRequestTB}`, минуя VM слой, раз он вам не нужен? Как видите, всегда есть нарушения правил, которые каждый делает осознано в своем проекте, ибо так проще... Вот и вы смотрите, нормально это для вас или нет, свое замечание про `DataContext` я там сказал, считаю это критичным, ну а свойства, тут уже сами решайте, нужна вам VM или нет, как сделал бы я, сказал тоже.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Спасибо огромное за замечания, но на счет свойств: я очень долго искал решения, но наконец я их нашел на этом же сайте, и пока не осмелюсь менять что-то, ибо может все поломаться, в принципе как у меня всегда происходит